# DNN redirect mobile with dynamic article ID

Tags: redirect, mobile, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 7 for my main site domain.com and m.domain.com for my mobile site. 
The main site uses DNN 7 but the mobile uses MVC. 
I am using fiftyOne to redirect my mobile site.
If I have 100 articles and this address to view a particular article: domain.com/default.aspx?id=n (where n=1-100). 
If someone click on this link on a mobile device then this take them to the mobile site: m.domain.com because I set it in the web config file. 
Is there a way to config so that it will take to the site m.domain.com/default.aspx?id=n ?
I heard that you can set the redirect rules in DNN but I am not sure if this can resolve the problem.
If you know the answer, please help.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I found your question a bit hard to understand. But I think what you want is to redirect mobile devices to the appropriate pages? If so, then:

In the block of code that you use to detect if requesting device is mobile or not you can implement the following code:

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
if (Request.Browser["IsMobile"] == "True")
{
    string mobile_url = "m." + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    Response.Redirect(mobile_url);
}
```

This should take the requested URL "domain.com/default.aspx?id=n", append "m." in front of it so the URL becomes "m.domain.com/default.aspx?id=n" and then issue a redirect to the mobile URL.

On a side note: having a separate version of the website for mobile devices is not advisable as search engines consider it a duplicate content.

Comment: Yes you are right. I ended up checking the request to see if this is from a mobile device and pass the url to redirect.
Thank you very much for your note. I think I will have to do it later. By the way, I did not put the BufferOut there. Is it important to set it?

Comment: Glad this was useful :) Not really, BufferOutput is set to true by default.